# MVIEW fast refresh always performing a select count(*) from master table before incrementing

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

Oracle version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Currently having an issue with a mview refresh where a small mview log takes ages to be added to mview due to a `select count(*) from [table]` being performed every time it starts.

- The on-demand mview fast refresh is triggered via a scheduled Oracle job
- Current setting (`dbms_mview_stats.set_mvref_stats_params`) is TYPICAL with 365 days retention.
- The mview refresh itself takes below 20s, the count(*) is the problem

After further checks, I noticed the table `USER_MVREF_CHANGE_STATS` has the column NUM_ROWS populated with the aforementioned row count that I believe comes from the `select count(*)` occurring every time.
We also noticed that `DBA_MVREF_STATS` contains values in `INITIAL_NUM_ROWS` and `FINAL_NUM_ROWS`.

**The idea is to bring this refresh back to what it should take which is ~30 seconds vs 1-2h right now.**

**Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? How can I stop this `select count(*)` from happening?**

Comment: Can you post a simple example that demonstrated this behaviour?

Comment: It's just that we monitored the sessions and saw that a select count(*) was being performed by the job.
Note that we actually changed dbms_mview_stats.set_mvref_stats_params to NONE and it fixed the issue.
We just don't know why a count(*) was being performed with TYPICAL setting.
We have this on other systems and the issue did not happen.